# How should I convert a firestore object into something I can use in expo/react-native?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, javascript-objects

This is the function I'm using to get all listings from my firestore instance. I would like to be able to retrieve the listings and add them to my listings page.

```
`function getListings() {
  db.collection('listings').get().then((snapshot)=> {
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      const id = doc.id
      const data = doc.data()

      console.log({id,data})
    })})`
```

This is what logs into the console. 2 separate listings. Both objects.

```
`Object {
  "data": Object {
    "amount": Object {
      "amount": "1000 ",
    },
    "category": Object {
      "category": Object {
        "backgroundColor": "purple",
        "label": "Fruits",
        "value": 1,
      },
    },
    "dateToday": Object {
      "dateToday": "Todays Date",
    },
    "description": Object {
      "description": "Crystal Clear",
    },
    "imageUris": Object {},
    "title": Object {
      "title": "Spring Water",
    },
    "userId": Object {
      "userId": "User Name",
    },
  },
  "id": "CB59J7NL7IXgKsUU6IyS",
}
Object {
  "data": Object {
    "amount": Object {
      "amount": "99",
    },
    "category": Object {
      "category": Object {
        "backgroundColor": "purple",
        "label": "Fruits",
        "value": 1,
      },
    },
    "dateToday": Object {
      "dateToday": "Todays Date",
    },
    "description": Object {
      "description": "Granny Smith",
    },
    "imageUris": Object {},
    "title": Object {
      "title": "Apples",
    },
    "userId": Object {
      "userId": "User Name",
    },
  },
  "id": "Tr2GjKES85HaSdeEOZwa",
}`
```

How can I convert the object into data that I can use? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You first should create a class. I called MyModel.

```
class MyModel {
    id="";
    data = "";
    category = ""; 
    dateToday = ""; 
    description =""; 
    imageUris =""; 
    userId =""; 

    constructor(props) {
        this.data = props && props.data || this.data;
        this.category = props && props.category || this.category;
        this.dateToday = props && props.dateToday || this.dateToday;
        this.description = props && props.description || this.description;
        this.imageUris = props && props.imageUris || this.imageUris;
        this.userId = props && props.userId || this.userId;
    }
}
```

after that update the function `getListings()` like below.

```
function getListings() {
        db.collection('listings').get().then((snapshot) => {
            const myObjects = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => new MyModel({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
        })
    }
```

Comment: I am happy to hear that.